# AdnEngine Particle System How many paticles update

Tags: android, andengine, particle-system

I need some idea on how to or some code example or anything related to this.

I have made some particle system, well here i will show from example of nicolas

```
final SpriteParticleSystem particleSystem = new SpriteParticleSystem(new PointParticleEmitter(-32, ParticleSystemNexusExample.CAMERA_HEIGHT - 32),
                                                                     ParticleSystemNexusExample.RATE_MIN, 
                                                                     ParticleSystemNexusExample.RATE_MAX, 
                                                                     ParticleSystemNexusExample.PARTICLES_MAX, 
                                                                     this.mParticleTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

What i need is to "LIVE" update the variable

```
private static final float RATE_MIN = 5;
private static final float RATE_MAX = 8;
private static int PARTICLES_MAX = 16;
```

Here is the the var from previous code

```
ParticleSystemNexusExample.RATE_MIN
ParticleSystemNexusExample.RATE_MAX
ParticleSystemNexusExample.PARTICLES_MAX
```

Is it possbile on some way?
Is possible to restart somehow particle system.
Well restarting it isnt 100% "live" update the system but i need to stay in app like using Settings and when u exit settings it will get new variables.

Basicly i have `onCreateScene` the `ParticleSystem();`

i use public void `ParticleSystem()`
{}

And is possible to restart it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what exactly you want to do, however Nicholas kept the min and max rate variables private on ParticleSystem class. I'm not sure what behavior you can get, but you can try to add a public interface for that and update it on real time to see what happens. If you don't want to mess with AndEngine platform code, here is a suggestion:

You can create two or more particle systems with different rates and manage them on screen according to your needs. If you you just want to swap them one time, simply detach the first and attach the second one. If you want to keep changing between them, you can use setParticlesSpawnEnabled to determine which one is active.

Cheers!

Comment: well, tryed with scene.deatachChildren(); after i attached it with new values from settings. Is that ok? detachChildren(); will destroy old Particle System and create new right?

Comment: Detach just remove it from the scene. You should only make sure you call it on engine update thread.

Comment: Well i used it on updatethread yes, deatach after new values attach. Is ok?